# How do I change dynamic page title while .load()

Tags: php, jquery

How to change my page title `<title></title>` after content is loaded in `#container` div?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.view").live('click', function () {
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        $('#container').load("view.php?" + id);
    });
});
```

If without `.load()` I retrieve it by get the `id` via URL, example `view.php?id=1`

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
 $pageid = intval($_GET['id']);
 $select = $db->query('SELECT id, title FROM content WHERE id="'.$id.'"');
 $data   = $db->fetch($select);
 $title  = $data['title'];
}
```

So in my `header.php` just call it `<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>`

If in this case file is load after `header.php` so how can I create dynamic my page title according to current `.load("view.php?" + id)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the [`document.title` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.title):

```
document.title = "My new title!";
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. How about if meta description? There have a specific element?

Comment: @kampit: You mean `<meta name="description" content="..." />`? There's no need. The description is only there for search bots, really, and they don't execute JavaScript.

Comment: Yes.. actually I want to change it for Open Graph Protocol purpose.

Comment: @kampit: Don't worry, that shouldn't matter either. Well, if it does... `$('meta[name=description]').attr('content', 'newValue')`

Comment: this will set the title immediately, instead of after the content has been loaded like he wanted.  Also @minitech, google has started a ajax crawling scheme, http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: @PatrickEvans: I didn't exactly mean "place it at the top of your code". This is how you set the title.

Comment: @PatrickEvans: It's okay. I just need a key point to start & the rest I will make further Googling :)

Answer (score 1):

add a callback function in the .load call, the responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest are all arguments that will be passed to the callback.

```
function myCallback(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)
{
    document.title = "Set new title";
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.view").live('click', function () {
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        $('#container').load("view.php?" + id,myCallback);
    });
});
```